# Hortonworks: Hbase, Hive, etc used for which type of data

Tags: hive, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform

I would like to ask if anyone could tell me or refer me to an internet page which describes all possibilities to store data in an apache hadoop cluster.

What I would like to know is: Which type of data should be stored in which "system". Under type of data I mean for example:

1. Live data (realtime)
2. Historical data
3. Data which is regularly accessed from an application
4. ...

The complete question is not reduced on Hbase or Hive ("System") but for everything which is available under Hdp.

I hope someone could lead me in a direction where i could find my answer. Thanks!

Comment: 'Hadoop: The Definitive Guide' by TM White

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an overview, but rest of the things you have to read on your own.

Let's begin with the types of data you want to store in HDFS:

1. **Data in Motion**(Which you denoted as real-time data).

So, how can you fetch the real-time data? Is it even possible? The answer is NO. There will always be a delay. However, we can reduce the downtime and processing time of the data. For which we have HDF(Hortonworks Data Flow). It works with the data in motion. There are many services providing the real-time data streaming. You can take the example of Kafka, Nifi, Storm and many more. These tools are used to process the data. You also need to store the data in such a way that you'd be able to fetch it no time(~2 sec), for that we use HBase. HBase stores the data in the columnar structure.

2. **Data at rest** (Historic/Data stored for future use)

So, to store the data at rest, there are no such issues. HDP(Hortonworks Data Platform) is there providing us the services to ingest, store and process the data. Even we can integrate HDF services to HDP(prior to version 2.6), which makes it easier to process Data in motion also. Here we need Databases to store a large amount of data. However, we are provided with HDFS(Hadoop Distributed File System) which can help us store any kind of data. But we don't ONLY want to store our data, we want to fetch it no time when it is required. So, how are we planning to do that? By storing our data in a structured form. For which we are provided Hive and HBase. To store such amount of data which is in TB, we need to run heavy processes that are where MapReduce, YARN, Spark, Kubernetes, Spark comes in to picture.

This is the basic idea of storing and processing data in Hadoop.

Rest you can always read from the internet.